# Rigid Body World

Tags: animation, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

I created a group of standard objects (cube, sphere and cone). I applied a *Rigid Body* modifier to each of the objects with standard settings.

Next, I created a separate file and using the Copy-Paste Objects method, I created three identical groups (A, B and C). How to properly bake the animation so that *Group A* starts falling at frame #50, *Group B* starts falling at frame #100, *Group C* at frame #150?

Here the *Floor* object is a passive element of the *Rigid Body* system. But for me, the algorithm itself (sequence of actions) for baking animation in a similar situation is important.

[image]

Comment: Blender version 3.0.

Comment: This has been dealt with elsewhere, but I don't feel like digging it up.  The easiest method is probably to animate deactivation on the rigid bodies.  Breakable constraints and non-rendering colliders are other possibilities.

Comment: @Nathan -- actually I took a look and am struggling, as you'll see by my "duplicate collection doesnt add to rigidbodyworld collection" https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253394/duplicate-collection-doesnt-add-to-rigidbodyworld-collection !   Otherwise yes, more or less animating the Dynamic checkbox (and perhaps copy/paste as driver in other objects).

Comment: Your question is a different question, where you are duplicating collections (and the answer is, don't duplicate collections, instead duplicate objects and, optionally, move them to new collections.)  Copy-pasting rigid body objects as Геннадий Горбач is doing, between instances of Blender, does not cause this problem (at least in 3.0 +, although it used to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Nathan part of the solution is to animate the Dynamic attribute of the Active RB (on frame 1 uncheck the Dynamic and click on the little dot to its right.

[image]

Then on the "start falling" frame #, click to enable Dynamic and click on what is now a diamond to set another keyframe.

Then on that animated object, right-click on Dyamic and Copy as New Driver,

[image]

and paste onto dynamic of all the other objects in that group.

[image]

[image]

In this way a change to the "start simulating" frame # on the first single object will affect the start time of the others in (your) Group A.

Now I run into an issue that if I Duplicate the Collection.  I am not getting these properly added to the Rigid Body World (a possible bug?).

(Again @Nathan added a similar comment to suggest the following.)
So I would next tell you to select all objects withing Group A, "D" (duplicate), and then move all of these to a New Group ("Group B"), and change the keyframe # for when to enable Dynamic simulation.

And so on for your other groups.

Comment: OK. Thank you. It works through Dynamic.