# Duplicate Collection doesn't add to RigidBodyWorld Collection

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

If I apply Rigid Body physics to objects in a collection, and then duplicate the collection:

[image]

The objects in that collection have the RB operator, but are not added to the RB World, even if I then Remove and reapply RB.   These objects don't participate in the RB simulation.

[image]

in the same way as if I duplicate objects within a collection and then move them to another collection.

[image]

1. Is there a reason for this exclusion of RBW Collection during the Duplicate Collection operation?
2. How can I coax my new, duplicated collection to be part of RBW, especially if I have several objects and want to avoid python scripting.  I am sometimes able to add an object to RBW, but I have to either copy/paste the name from the Scene, an it sometimes fights me by creating a RBW.001 where some objects are still not included.

Here's an example [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is the "invisible" RigidBodyWorld collection, which you can find here:

[image]

You have to add this collection to your objects (RigidBodyWorld) of your new collection, then it works.

[image]